# Importing dictionary from a different path in my project

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Im trying to figure how import a large dictionary list from a different path. I would like to work with a dictionary on a different file so my program could look neater as I work on it.

```
import heapq

x = raw_input()
y = raw_input()

def shortestPath(start, end):
    queue,seen = [(0, start, [])], set()
    while True:
        (cost, v, path) = heapq.heappop(queue)
        if v not in seen:
            path = path + [v]
            seen.add(v)
            if v == end:
                return cost, path
            for (next, c) in graph[v].iteritems():
                heapq.heappush(queue, (cost + c, next, path))


graph = {
   'a': {'w': 16, 'x': 9, 'y': 11},
   'b': {'w': 11, 'z': 8},
   'w': {'a': 16, 'b': 11, 'y': 4},
   'x': {'a': 9, 'y': 12, 'z': 17},
   'y': {'a': 11, 'w': 4, 'x': 12, 'z': 13},
   'z': {'b': 8, 'x': 17, 'y': 13},
}
cost, path = shortestPath(x, y)
print cost
```

So this a part of the program with the small dictionary that I stated with, but I have made it way bigger on another file.  I would like to delete the the small dictionary and import the bigger graph from another file. The other file is called Graph.py

Comment: Make a class that has a module. The module can return dictionary. **class.YourDictionary()** kind of syntax

Comment: Did you try `from Graph import graph`?

Comment: @Selcuk - I did try 'from Graph import graph' , But it stay gray and it says that 'graph' has no attribute

Comment: What is the content of Graph.py and where is it located relative to the above script?

Comment: @Selcuk - So the content is similar to the example I showed, but with way more data. Its located in the same project folder as the program shown above.

Comment: @SpiderMan - Im trying what you suggest it, but im having trouble figuring it out. Im going keep trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main.py

```
    import heapq
    import Graph

    x = raw_input()
    y = raw_input()

    def shortestPath(start, end):
        queue,seen = [(0, start, [])], set()
        while True:
            (cost, v, path) = heapq.heappop(queue)
            if v not in seen:
                path = path + [v]
                seen.add(v)
                if v == end:
                    return cost, path
                for (next, c) in graph[v].iteritems():
                    heapq.heappush(queue, (cost + c, next, path))


    graph = Graph.graph
    cost, path = shortestPath(x, y)
    print cost
```

Your Graph.py

```
graph = {
   'a': {'w': 16, 'x': 9, 'y': 11},
   'b': {'w': 11, 'z': 8},
   'w': {'a': 16, 'b': 11, 'y': 4},
   'x': {'a': 9, 'y': 12, 'z': 17},
   'y': {'a': 11, 'w': 4, 'x': 12, 'z': 13},
   'z': {'b': 8, 'x': 17, 'y': 13},
}#add your complex dictionary
```

You can import graph from Graph.py like variable.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class containing the definition of your dictionary as an attribute in a first file `file_1`:

```
class myDictionary():
    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionary = {'a': {'w': 16, 'x': 9, 'y': 11},
                           'b': {'w': 11, 'z': 8},
                           'w': {'a': 16, 'b': 11, 'y': 4},
                           'x': {'a': 9, 'y': 12, 'z': 17},
                           'y': {'a': 11, 'w': 4, 'x': 12, 'z': 13},
                           'z': {'b': 8, 'x': 17, 'y': 13},}

    def getDictionary(self):
        return self.dictionary
```

Then in the second file `file_2`, simply create an instance of your class and call the function that will return you the dictionary.

```
import file_1

graph = file_1.myDictionary().getDictionary()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider having the data in the pervasive json format and just importing it like

```
import json
import sys

def main(fn):
  with open(fn) as f:
      graph = json.load(f)
  x = raw_input()
  y = raw_input()
  cost, _ = shortest_path(graph, x, y)
  print cost

def shortest_path(graph, x, y):
   # .... Your code. Notice that i've given graph as an argument here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

And then run your script like
`python yourscript.py mygraph.json`

Where mygraph.json is something like:

```
{
  "a": {
    "y": 11, 
    "x": 9, 
    "w": 16
  }, 
  "b": {
    "z": 8, 
    "w": 11
  }, 
  "w": {
    "a": 16, 
    "y": 4, 
    "b": 11
  }, 
  "y": {
    "a": 11, 
    "x": 12, 
    "z": 13, 
    "w": 4
  }, 
  "x": {
    "a": 9, 
    "y": 12, 
    "z": 17
  }, 
  "z": {
    "y": 13, 
    "x": 17, 
    "b": 8
  }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion is great, but he only issue if that "shortestPath" function is an example of part of the program. If I incorporate this it will change the way the program behaves. I was looking to see if I can make it work with "from Graph import *" or another way.